# run composer and laravel (artisan) commands without ssh access

Tags: php, shell, laravel, ssh

I want to test some Laravel applications on my basic shared host.

Currently I just upload my complete application including the vendor files, however this takes quite long.

Since I do not have `ssh` access to my host I'd like to know whether there's an option to run composer / artisan commands without this.

I found this link: [Use Composer without ssh access to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969948/use-composer-without-ssh-access-to-server) (Second Answer) which describes how to run composer using http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/

However, I can change folders in the console etc. But I cannot run php commands - I always get internal server error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if your shared hosting provider has `console` feature in their CP which allows to run shell commands. Maybe you'll be able to run commands from there.

As alternative, you could right your own artisan runner and [call artisan commands from the code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code):

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

To run composer command from PHP code, use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php):

```
shell_exec('composer update');
```

Comment: shell_exec mostly disabled for security reason in shared hosting