# Use composer on a small linux webservice

Tags: php, linux, ssh, instagram

I'm developing an application using PHP. for which I need to use this library: [mgp25/instagram-api](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)

It uses composer to auto load libraries but I can't install composer on my server because the company from which I got my web-service doesn't support **SSH Access**, As I found in : [Use Composer without ssh access to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969948/use-composer-without-ssh-access-to-server)

The best way is to make "`vendor/autoload.php`" on another server/computer and then to upload it on my server, Since I don't have a Linux server and I even don't know how to use it, I want to ask is there anybody who can make the file "`vendor/autoload.php`" for me? is it possible at all?

Comment: I doubt this makes sense at all. The benefit of composer is that it can automatically pull in dependencies when updates are required or a new deployment is done. None of this will work for you, so why invest into this? Why not simply install the required libraries manually and all is fine?

Comment: Composer don't require exclusive use through SSH, you can use through HTTP as well. Are your composer behind a proxy?

Comment: I just want the library to work, Doesn't matter it'll be able to update or not, plus I can't simply install required libraries manually, I'm almost new to PHP, so there are a lot to learn for me. So please help me get this library work, doesn't matter which way.

Comment: I also don't know how to use it through HTTP. It would be appreciated if you help me.